# SqlCeResultSet and SQL injection

Tags: sql-server, compact-framework, sql-injection

When using this code to insert a row with SqlCeResultSet,

```
SqlCeResultSet resultSet = DataAccess.OpenResultSet("MyTable");
SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = resultSet.CreateRecord();
record.SetString(1,TextBox1.Text);
resultSet.Insert(record);
```

Does it prevent SQL injection attacks?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will prevent injection attacks. SetString will place the string into the column as passed in. There is no need to escape the string etc.